# XSLT XPath: If one child node is updated, take data from different child node (for the same worker) - how to handle?

Tags: xml, xpath, xslt-2.0, transformation, workday-api

Here's my XML (see question below it):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Worker_Effective_Stack_Aggregate>
<Pay_Group Name="Exempt">
    <Worker>
        <Summary>
            <Employee_ID>12345</Employee_ID>
        </Summary>
        <Effective_Change>
            <Derived_Event_Code>PGO</Derived_Event_Code>
            <Position isUpdated="1">
                <Business_Title>Test Worker</Business_Title>
                <Position_End_Date isAdded="1">6/30/2021</Position_End_Date>
            </Position>
        </Effective_Change>
    </Worker>
</Pay_Group>
<Pay_Group Name="Non-Exempt">
    <Worker>
        <Summary>
            <Employee_ID>11111</Employee_ID>
        </Summary>
        <Effective_Change>
            <Derived_Event_Code>PGI</Derived_Event_Code>
            <Position isAdded="1">
                <Business_Title>Wrong Test Worker</Business_Title>
            </Position>
        </Effective_Change>
    </Worker>
    <Worker>
        <Summary>
            <Employee_ID>12345</Employee_ID>
        </Summary>
        <Effective_Change>
            <Derived_Event_Code>PGI</Derived_Event_Code>
            <Position isAdded="1">
                <Business_Title>Senior Test Worker</Business_Title>
            </Position>
        </Effective_Change>
    </Worker>
</Pay_Group>
</Worker_Effective_Stack_Aggregate>
```

**Question**: do you know how to write a code which will follow this scenario: '**if the event code is 'PGO' and the worker's position is updated with an end date**, look for **the 'PGI' events on the entire file for the worker with the same ID as the worker who had that 'PGO' event** and deliver **value of <Business_Title>**, which in this case is 'Senior Test Worker'.

Here's my XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xtt="urn:com.workday/xtt" version="2.0">
                
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:variable name="SEPARATOR" select="','" as="xs:string"/>
<xsl:variable name="NEWLINE" select="'&#xD;&#xA;'" as="xs:string"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <File>
        <Header xtt:endTag="{$NEWLINE}" xtt:separator="{$SEPARATOR}">
            <Business_Title>Business Title</Business_Title>
        </Header>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Worker_Effective_Stack_Aggregate/Pay_Group/Worker"/>
    </File>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Worker">
    <Employee xtt:endTag="{$NEWLINE}" xtt:separator="{$SEPARATOR}" xtt:quotes="never">
    
        <Business_Title>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="Effective_Change/Derived_Event_Code = 'PGO'">
                    <xsl:value-of select="../../../Worker_Effective_Stack_Aggregate/Pay_Group/Worker [Effective_Change/Derived_Event_Code = 'PGI' and Summary/Employee_ID = '12345']/Effective_Change/Position/Business_Title"/>
                </xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
        </Business_Title>

    </Employee>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**If you need a background for all the above**: in our HCM system 'Workday', whenever someone changes both pay groups and position, Workday creates two events for them, one called 'PGO' (pay group outbound) and second called 'PGI' (pay group inbound). If the position is changed, the new one is only reflected in the 'PGI' event and I need to somehow bring it into the 'PGO' event details.

**Expected output**:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<File xmlns:xtt="urn:com.workday/xtt">
  <Header xtt:endTag="&#13;&#10;" xtt:separator=",">
    <Business_Title>Business Title</Business_Title>
  </Header>
  <Employee xtt:endTag="&#13;&#10;" xtt:separator="," xtt:quotes="never">
    <Business_Title>Senior Test Worker</Business_Title>
  </Employee>
  <Employee xtt:endTag="&#13;&#10;" xtt:separator="," xtt:quotes="never">
    <Business_Title/>
  </Employee>
  <Employee xtt:endTag="&#13;&#10;" xtt:separator="," xtt:quotes="never">
    <Business_Title/>
  </Employee>
</File>
```

Comment: Well, you have various conditions you can easily express as XPath expressions with predicates and you want to follow cross-references so use keys. How easy and compact that approach will be depends a bit on the XSLT version so you should add that information to the question and the tags.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I have now added the 'xslt 2.0' tag.

Comment: Start writing some XPath expressions then, expressing e.g. "if the event code is 'PGO'" in XPath is not that hard, any XPath tutorial should give you an easy access, even if you are completely new to XPath. As for XSLT, consult your favourite XSLT tutorial on keys.

Comment: Thanks Martin. In terms of the 'xsl:when' part I was able to achieve what I need but I'm getting stuck in the 'xsl:value-of' part when I need to somehow tell the transformation to 'now go back to the entire file, search for all 'PGI' events and fetch me the title but only from the 'PGI' event for the same worker on your 'PGO' event'.
Actually I can even achieve the 'now go back to the entire file...' but I don't know how to tell it to focus only on the 'PGI' for the same worker in question.

Comment: I can do it like this, but I'm obviously simply telling it which worker it is (by writing ID). I need it to figure it out itself (as there may be 20+ different workers on the file):

<xsl:value-of select="../../Worker_Effective_Stack_Aggregate/Pay_Group/Worker [Effective_Change/Derived_Event_Code = 'PGI' and Summary/Employee_ID = '12345']/Effective_Change/Position/Business_Title"/>

Comment: Post minimal but complete sample of the XSLT you have, the result you want, the result you currently get and how you are stuck. Do that by editing the question, not by putting code into comments.

Comment: I have now added my complete XSL and XSLT (with that 'Summary/Employee_ID = '12345'' that I would like to replace by itself figuring it out). What do you think about it?

Comment: I have edited my answer to show an adaption of your attempt to use `current()` to compare and relate the two elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a key and template based matching you can pull in the title from the related element with

```
  <xsl:key name="bus-title-by-id"
           match="Worker/Effective_Change[Derived_Event_Code = 'PGI']/Position/Business_Title" 
           use="ancestor::Worker/Summary/Employee_ID"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="Worker/Effective_Change[Derived_Event_Code = 'PGO']/Position[@isUpdated = 1][Position_End_Date]/Business_Title[key('bus-title-by-id', ancestor::Worker/Summary/Employee_ID)]">
    <xsl:sequence select="key('bus-title-by-id', ancestor::Worker/Summary/Employee_ID)"/>
  </xsl:template>
```

If the rest of the document needs to be copied unchanged, hanlde that by using the identity transformation template

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

As for your own code, now added, use `current()` to compare the two elements (i.e. the one matched to the other you looking up):

```
<xsl:template match="Worker">
    <Employee xtt:endTag="{$NEWLINE}" xtt:separator="{$SEPARATOR}" xtt:quotes="never">
    
        <Business_Title>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="Effective_Change/Derived_Event_Code = 'PGO'">
                    <xsl:value-of select="../../../Worker_Effective_Stack_Aggregate/Pay_Group/Worker [Effective_Change/Derived_Event_Code = 'PGI' and Summary/Employee_ID = current()/Summary/Employee_ID]/Effective_Change/Position/Business_Title"/>
                </xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
        </Business_Title>

    </Employee>
</xsl:template>
```

In the end the use of a key makes such lookups much faster and more efficient:

```
<xsl:template match="Worker">
    <Employee xtt:endTag="{$NEWLINE}" xtt:separator="{$SEPARATOR}" xtt:quotes="never">
    
        <Business_Title>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="Effective_Change/Derived_Event_Code = 'PGO'">
                    <xsl:value-of select="key('bus-title-by-id', Summary/Employee_ID)"/>
                </xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
        </Business_Title>

    </Employee>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:key name="bus-title-by-id"
           match="Worker/Effective_Change[Derived_Event_Code = 'PGI']/Position/Business_Title" 
           use="ancestor::Worker/Summary/Employee_ID"/>
```

In both the last samples the `xsl:choose/when` seem unnecessarily complicated and a simple `xsl:if` should suffice instead.

Comment: Martin, you're the man! That 'current()/Summary/Employee_ID' trick is exactly what I was desperately looking for. Thank you very, very much. It may seems like a simple trick to you but man, that helped me a LOT!